# Append not working in jQuery v1.11.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append anchor tag in a div but unfortunately its not working:

Following is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test-inner').append('<a href="#" class="new-img-holder"></a>');
  $('.test-image').appendTo('.new-img-holder');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-inner">
  <img class="test-image" src="cine-sudarshan.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `fancybox-inner`?

Comment: sorry, I just update my JS

Comment: Your code is okay. The bug must lie somewhere else.

Comment: Your code is working

Comment: Please note that I am using jQuery v1.11.3, I tested with higher version and it was working well, but not with this version

Comment: Do you get any messages in the console?

Comment: I created a snippet for you using 1.11.3 and it works for me in Chrome

Comment: Voting to close this question as it's clearly not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working even with `V1.2.3`

It is certainly linked to another part of your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.test-inner').append('<a href="#" class="new-img-holder"></a>');   
  $('.test-image').appendTo('.new-img-holder');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-inner">
    <img class="test-image" src="cine-sudarshan.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: What are you answering for?